# Supblots to include radar plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot, radar-chart

I'm running into issues with some subplots.  I've provided some sample code to generate the types of plots I would like to create.  I'd like these to be the same size, side by side.

I'm am having a really hard time figuring out how to create the subplots though. I keep running into some issues with the thetagrids here.  This is what i've tried.  I can get these to work seprarately, but cant figure out how to combine them.  Eventually I might want a third plot as well.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


## Plot 1
x1 = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3])
y1 = np.array([7, 2, 4, 2])

plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)
plt.figure(figsize=(5, 5))
plt.scatter(x1, y1)

# plt.show()

### Plot 2
# make up data for plot
polar_list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'a']
polar_points = [4, 3, 6, 7, 4]

# modify lists for plots
label_loc = np.linspace(start=0, stop=2 * np.pi, num=len(polar_list))
plt.figure(figsize=(5, 5))
plt.subplot(1, 2, 2, polar=True)

plt.plot(label_loc, polar_points, label='DataLable')

plt.title('DataLable comparison', size=20, y=1.05)

lines, labels = plt.thetagrids(np.degrees(label_loc), labels=polar_list)

plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image: Basically what i'm going for]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating a new figure every time you call `plt.figure()`. Just place one at the very beginning and then the `plt.subplot()` will add subplots to the figures.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


## Plot 1
x1 = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3])
y1 = np.array([7, 2, 4, 2])

plt.figure(figsize= (5, 5))

plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)

plt.scatter(x1, y1)

# plt.show()

### Plot 2
# make up data for plot
polar_list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'a']
polar_points = [4, 3, 6, 7, 4]

# modify lists for plots
label_loc = np.linspace(start=0, stop=2 * np.pi, num=len(polar_list))
plt.subplot(1, 2, 2, polar=True)

plt.plot(label_loc, polar_points, label='DataLable')

plt.title('DataLable comparison', size=20, y=1.05)

lines, labels = plt.thetagrids(np.degrees(label_loc), labels=polar_list)

plt.legend()
plt.show()
```